# Finding most important patent of a company

Tags: uspto, google-patents, citation, important

Is there a way to find most important patents for any company for example: Apple or any other company?

On google patents, I can search for patents assigned to a particular company, is there a way to sort them using citations, which might reflect the importance of the patents?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) for patent searching. It has a lot more features than Google Patents and if you create an account, which is totally free, you get yet more features. You can search by patent owner and can sort by number of citations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eric, I will check out The Lens.